# GLFW create window is failing on a windows virtual machine

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, virtualbox, glfw

I am trying to create a window with the latest version of GLFW in c++ on the latest version of windows running on a virualbox virtual machine.

```
        m_Window = glfwCreateWindow(m_Width, m_Height, m_Name, NULL, NULL);

        if (!m_Window)
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        }
```

The following code sends the message "Failed to create GLFW window" as expected if it fails to create a window. I am following a tutorial so I know this code works.

(Note all variables are predefined correctly)

I have a feeling that it has to do with virtualbox's display drivers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Likely you're trying to create a window with OpenGL hints that need an OGL version that the virtualbox machine doesn't support.

Comment: I have used GL inside VMs, but it was VmWare. See this link for more info: https://github.com/Const-me/GL3Windows#building-and-running